# Problema con envio de mail desde XAMPP por fallo en smtp_port en php.ini

Tags: php, xampp, smtp

Estoy usando el código de un registro de usuario que envía notificaciones a dicho usuario vía email bajo XAMPP pero muestra error al enviar el mail.

Estoy usando el código de un registro de usuario que envía notificaciones a dicho usuario vía email. Lo estoy haciendo bajo XAMPP pero hay algo que no funciona al enviar el mail al usuario.
El error que muestra es:

```
Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\xampp\htdocs\SistemaLoginPHP\PhpRegistrationFormMail\register.php on line 60
Please check your email to activate your account!
```

Estoy usando este código en "register.php":
`

```
<?php
// Change this to your connection info.
$DATABASE_HOST = 'localhost';
$DATABASE_USER = 'root';
$DATABASE_PASS = '';
$DATABASE_NAME = 'phplogin';
// Try and connect using the info above.
$con = mysqli_connect($DATABASE_HOST, $DATABASE_USER, $DATABASE_PASS, $DATABASE_NAME);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    // If there is an error with the connection, stop the script and display the error.
    exit('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Now we check if the data was submitted, isset() function will check if the data exists.
if (!isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['email'])) {
    // Could not get the data that should have been sent.
    exit('Please complete the registration form!');
}
// Make sure the submitted registration values are not empty.
if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password']) || empty($_POST['email'])) {
    // One or more values are empty.
    exit('Please complete the registration form');
}

// We need to check if the account with that username exists.
if ($stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT id, password FROM accounts WHERE username = ?')) {
    if (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        exit('Email is not valid!');
    }
    if (preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $_POST['username']) == 0) {
        exit('Username is not valid!');
    }
    if (strlen($_POST['password']) > 20 || strlen($_POST['password']) < 5) {
        exit('Password must be between 5 and 20 characters long!');
    }
    // Bind parameters (s = string, i = int, b = blob, etc), hash the password using the PHP password_hash function.
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['username']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    // Store the result so we can check if the account exists in the database.
    if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
        // Username already exists
        echo 'Username exists, please choose another!';
    } else {
        
        // Username doesn't exists, insert new account
        if ($stmt = $con->prepare('INSERT INTO accounts (username, password, email, activation_code) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)')) {
            // We do not want to expose passwords in our database, so hash the password and use password_verify when a user logs in.
            $password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
            $uniqid = uniqid();
            $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $_POST['username'], $password, $_POST['email'], $uniqid);

            $stmt->execute();
            $from    = 'noreply@yourdomain.com';
            $subject = 'Account Activation Required';
            $headers = 'From: ' . $from . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $from . "\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion() . "\r\n" . 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" . 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
            // Update the activation variable below
            $activate_link = 'http://yourdomain.com/phplogin/activate.php?email=' . $_POST['email'] . '&code=' . $uniqid;
            $message = '<p>Please click the following link to activate your account: <a href="' . $activate_link . '">' . $activate_link . '</a></p>';
            mail($_POST['email'], $subject, $message, $headers);
            echo 'Please check your email to activate your account!';
            
        } else {
            // Something is wrong with the SQL statement, so you must check to make sure your accounts table exists with all 3 fields.
            echo 'Could not prepare statement!';
        }
        
    }
    $stmt->close();
} else {
    // Something is wrong with the SQL statement, so you must check to make sure your accounts table exists with all 3 fields.
    echo 'Could not prepare statement!';
}
$con->close();
?>`
```

Pienso que tiene mas que ver con la configuración del "php.ini" en XAMPP que con el código en si ya que es un ejemplo que funciona ya que lo extraje de un tutorial.
El error que marca coincide con la linea:

```
` mail($_POST['email'], $subject, $message, $headers);`
```

¿Alguién sabría que debería tener en cuenta para hacer que esos mails se envíen desde XAMPP? ¿Debo cambiar algo en php.ini? ¿Cómo puedo probar el envío de estos mails desde XAMPP?

Comment: La función mail() de php es un pseudo-smtp muy simple hecho para pruebas, por lo que no es raro que no funcione en [muchos casos](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mail.php#refsect1-function.mail-notes). Recomiendo usar [phpmailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), es muy sencillo de usar, funciona en cualquier plataforma y hay muchos [ejemplos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=phpmailer) por ahí.

Comment: He intentado usar phpmailer pero parece que no hace mucho gmail restringió su uso, tan solo admite ahora acceso a dispositivos de terceros cuando cambias tu cuenta a "registro en dos pasos". Eso no es válido para mi puesto que el envío de mensajes no es gratuito. ¿No existe otra manera?

Comment: Eso depende cómo lo vas a usar.  Para enviar mensajes a un correo gmail no es problema, pero si vas a usar una cuenta de gmail como enviador ya es otro cuento. Y si no funciona con phpmailer, mucho menos con la función `mail()` integrada. Investigando por internet puedo ver que hay formas de hacer funcionar [phpmailer con gmail](https://www.google.com/search?q=phpmailer+gmail+2022).

Comment: Sí, he investigado los ejemplos. En todos se usa la "verificación en 2 pasos" de gmail. Esto no me gusta mucho ya que entran en juego sms o llamadas que seguro supondrán un gasto. Me queda por ver la opción de XOAUTH2. No sé como funciona. Tendré que investigar. ¿Sabrías tú algo sobre XOAUTH2?